# No downtime replacement of EC2 fleet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, continuous-deployment, fleet

I need to bounce a fleet of 100 EC2 hosts and would like to bounce at a 20% increment. What are some automated options I can pursue? So far, I found this script:

https://github.com/colinbjohnson/aws-missing-tools/blob/master/aws-ha-release/aws-ha-release.sh

I'd assume this is a common enough problem that it should be kind of a solved problem although I do not really see a lot of solutions listed online other than conversations about Elastic Beanstalk (which does not seem to fit my use case)

Comment: How far have you gone with your infrastructure? You could deploy a new load balancer and slowly move traffic from A to B, killing old EC2s as you go?

Comment: The infra is quite mature. I'd prefer the ELB address to be static, since it's tied to some route 53 settings. However, I am all ears for ideas.

Comment: Yeah - another option is if you have an application load balancer rather than ELB you can switch the target group almost instantly. You could move to an ALB using the same EC2 instances in preparation.

Comment: Or with ELB classic, add new instances to the balancer, then remove the old ones once the new ones are healthy and in service.  Not instantaneous, of course.

Comment: That's great but won't work if you have different versions of your application